# How to refer to the local parameters in Angualr within a function

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 14. I've a repetitive piece of code. I decided to make it generic but I'm not able to refer to the parameters passed to that generic method because Objects are involved in my code.  Whenever I use the passed parameter with object with dot (.) operator, the compiler starts treating it as an actual key and throws error that key is not found.

**Initial code without generic method:**

```
  setAllInputFields() {

    // this code repeats
    if (this.recordSpecificData.fruitBox.length === 0) {
      this.myReactiveForm
        .get('boxDetails.fruitBoxNumber')
        ?.setValue('not found');
    } else {
      const activeStatus = this.recordSpecificData.fruitBox.find(
        (item: any) => item.fruitOrderStatus === 'A'
      );
      this.myReactiveForm
        .get('boxDetails.fruitBoxNumber')
        ?.setValue(activeStatus.fruitBoxNumber);
    }

    // this code repeats
    if (this.recordSpecificData.vegetableBox.length === 0) {
      this.myReactiveForm
        .get('boxDetails.vegetableBoxNumber')
        ?.setValue('not found');
    } else {
      const activeStatus = this.recordSpecificData.vegetableBox.find(
        (item: any) => item.vegetableOrderStatus === 'A'
      );
      this.myReactiveForm
        .get('boxDetails.vegetableBoxNumber')
        ?.setValue(activeStatus.vegetableBoxNumber);
    }

   // this code repeats 15 more times
}
```

Notice that in every repeated code only `fruitBox` , `fruitBoxNumber`, `fruitOrderStatus` and similarly `vegetableBox` , `vegetableBoxNumber`, `vegetableOrderStatus` are changing. So I decided to make a generic method which will accept 3 parameters:

**I tried:**

```
  // For e.g. arg1 will be box type, arg2 will be box number and arg3 will be order status
  genericMethod(arg1: any, arg2: any, arg3: any) {
    if (this.recordSpecificData.arg1.length === 0) {
      this.partsDetailsReactiveForm
        .get('partsDetails.'+arg2)
        ?.setValue('not found');
    } else {
      const activeStatus = this.recordSpecificData.arg1.find(
        (item: any) => item.arg3 === 'A'
      );
      this.partsDetailsReactiveForm
        .get('partsDetails.'+arg2)
        ?.setValue(activeStatus.arg2);
    }
  }
```

But as you can see the problem. compiler will start looking for things like `this.recordSpecificData.arg1` and `item.arg3`. this is causing the failure. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

That's called "dot notation". There's another way to access properties in object which is `bracket notation`.

```
var a = 'key'; var obj = {key: 1}
obj.a = obj['a'] => return undefined as obj doesn't have property a
obj[a] = obj['key'] => return 1
```